# decodeByteArray data from onPictureTaken callback returns null

Tags: android

There are similar questions like this on SO but none of them matches my specific situation.

I am implementing camera controls using the official [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera).

The way I take shot is by invoking `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this)` and then receiving the callback from `onPictureTaken`. The problem I am having is I can't seem to `decodeByteArray` the data being passed onto `onPictureTaken`. `decodeByteArray` keeps on returning null. It seems the format of the byte array is invalid.

I tried saving the byte array via a `FileOutputStream` as is, just as in the tutorial and then read the bytes back again via `decodeFile` and it still returns null. I tried capturing exceptions but none was caught.

Take note that I can save the photo just fine. I cannot read the bytes from the argument passed. I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String fileName =  Photo.getDirectory(this) + "/Confirm_" + mDateFormatter.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";

    try
    {
        File temp = new File(fileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();

        try
        {
            // This always returns NULL
            BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            option.inSampleSize = 2;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, option);

            if(bitmap == null) ; // TRUE
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
        Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);

        for(Camera.Size s : sizes)
        {
            Log.i(PhotoApplication.TAG, "Size : " + s.width + " x " + s.height);
        }
        */

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FILENAME, temp.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + temp.getName());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saving as : " + temp.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + temp.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(out != null)
                out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

According to the document

> If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

remove it or set it to `false` if your want to decode bitmap for later use.

Comment: damn... this is a slap to my face. Thank you very much!